# <uses feature> tan in android

Tags: android, manifest

> ```
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PHONE_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
> <uses-permission   
>   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_USER_DICTIONARY" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_USER_DICTIONARY" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
> <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.location"
>     android:required="false" />
> <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
>     android:required="false" />
>  <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
>     android:required="false" />
>   <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.wifi"
>     android:required="false" />
> <uses-feature
>     android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
>     android:required="false" />
> <uses-feature
>     android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
>     android:required="true" />
> ```

I have basically declares this in the manifest. I want to know what exactly uses feature does.

From my understanding, if i declared permission access_coarse_location and all that, this means my app uses feature android.hardware.location ..and for that automatically thats set for true.
By specifying that feature to false, am telling android store..that a user can download this app even if he doesn't have location hardware..because this thing is handled inside code?

Is my understanding right? Because i find it funny there is feature android.hardware.wifi ..
what phone, mobile device doesn't have a wifi?

Comment: Very few devices do not have WiFi (some watches, for example), but there are some devices in the AndroidTV space that are Ethernet-only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yup your understanding is correct.

From https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element:

> Google Play uses the  elements declared in your app
>   manifest to filter your app from devices that do not meet it's
>   hardware and software feature requirements. By specifying the features
>   that your application requires, you enable Google Play to present your
>   application only to users whose devices meet the application's feature
>   requirements, rather than presenting it to all users

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know what exactly uses feature does

Quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html):

> The purpose of a  declaration is to inform any external entity of the set of hardware and software features on which your application depends. The element offers a required attribute that lets you specify whether your application requires and cannot function without the declared feature, or whether it prefers to have the feature but can function without it. Because feature support can vary across Android devices, the  element serves an important role in letting an application describe the device-variable features that it uses.

Here, "external entity" usually means an app distribution channel, like the Play Store.

> Is my understanding right?

Yes. One role of `<uses-feature>` is to indicate that some feature is *not* required, where [a permission would imply that it is required](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions).

> Because i find it funny there is feature android.hardware.wifi .. what phone, mobile device doesn't have a wifi?

There is no requirement that Android devices support WiFi. For example, Android is used in vehicles, from cars to the Boeing 787 Dreamliner, and those environments may not offer WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in your understanding. The `uses` tag is mainly for filtering on the play store. Which means that users who may have a device that doesn't support a **required** feature that your app depends on, will not see your app in the listings.

As an aside. There are plenty of Android devices which don't feature a wireless chipset. I've been working with Android based Barcode scanners that don't have Wifi, nor GPS services. It's always best to handle things in code, depending on what the device is capable of.

Hope this helps.